# Where does the cookie "mp_super_properties" come from?

Tags: cookies, session-cookies

When I check which cookies have been set for my website I noticed there is a cookie called:

```
'mp_super_properties'
```

My app didn't create this cookie. But which app did?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from mixpanel the data tracking service.